# Audio Inculcation and Learning

Tags: learning, educational-psychology, conditioning

Suppose I have an audio file of a lecture of a professor explaining something to be learned - a physics concept for example, and I listen to the audio file over and over again, much like how people listen to music while working.

How effective is audio inculcation - listening to an audio file over and over again, even though I'm doing something else and not actively listening to the audio - for learning? How does this affect the subconscious?

Can this tactic be used to change  behavior: For example, recording a voice of  saying "Do not go on Facebook. Facebook is bad.," and listening it to it over and over again, much like one would do with music.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This LOP diagram explains it pretty well, acoustic information is remembered moderately well as it has moderate processing done on it to help you remember it, but as you can see, semantic  is the best way to remember stuff, something is semantic if it's understood well or has meaning to you, so the best way to learn it is it to make sure that you understand it!

[image]

Comment: What is "physical" learning?

Comment: Physical, or visual learning. Learning which is done through images/ reading e.t.c..

Comment: How do these numbers spread? I personally got the impression that when I listen to something a remember least...

Comment: I'm not sure of the exact numbers, however the graph is a perfect representation of it I find.